# Sorting by Received and THEN Subject

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

Can Outlook 2003 sort by received and then subject so that I can always see the newest mail first? So if it's 5:30pm now and I get mail at 5:31, it shows at the top. then if I get mail at 5:35 and it is a response to an existing subject, can it show next at the top of my inbox with all related conversations/subjects with it. Gmail can do this and this is what I'm looking for an Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

Lifehacker has an article on [how to make Outlook act like GMail](http://lifehacker.com/157042/make-outlook-thread-conversations-like-gmail):

> To mimic Gmail's threads we need a way for Outlook to group by subject, but ignore the FW: and RE:. Luckily, it has just such a feature. It's called Conversation, and it's an optional column just like date received and subject.
>
> In your Inbox, go to the pane that lists your emails. Right-click any of the field headings, like From, or Subject, and select Field Chooser. You'll get a list of additional fields that pertain to your emails. Click and drag Conversation to the other field headings. You'll notice it looks just like subject, but ignores FW: and RE:.